# How can i handle [WinError 10057] error in python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Exercise 1: Change the socket program socket1.py to prompt the user
for the URL so it can read any web page. You can use split('/') to
break the URL into its component parts so you can extract the host
name for the socket connect call. Add error checking using try and
except to handle the condition where the user enters an improperly
formatted or non-existent URL.

```
import socket
url = input('name:')
word = url.split('/')
host = word[2]
print(host)
try:
    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect(('host', 80))
    mysock.send(('GET '+url+' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n').encode())

except:
    print ("Try your best")

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

mysock.close()
```

OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

would you please help me? why code return me this error? how can I resolve it without any other new function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mysock.connect(('host', 80))
```

Should be

```
    mysock.connect((host, 80))
```

Comment: you should also format the send function parameters better using format() or f strings

Comment: Would you please explain it a little more,I am n coursera course and I don't know should I learn more that that or not,bcz when I read trough Internet there are lots of function for socket which I do not know at all.

Comment: if you wanna add me on discord ShadowMuffin#6671 I can help you out in detail